# PIL/Pillow: one cycle for multiple lists of im.getdata()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have this code which analyse, for one image, all pixel values and calculates if each color is nearest to black or white with Euclidean distance formula:

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt
im=Image.open("7.jpg")
size=128,128
im.thumbnail(size)
colors=im.getdata()
darklist=[]
lightlist=[]
dark=0
light=0
for item in colors:
    if sqrt((item[0]-255)**2 + (item[1]-255)**2 + (item[2]-255)**2) < sqrt((item[0]-0)**2 + (item[1]-0)**2 + (item[2]-0)**2):
        lightlist.append(item)
        light+=1
    else:
        darklist.append(item)
        dark+=1
print ("Total light pixels=",light)
print ("Total dark pixels=",dark)

if len(darklist) > len(lightlist):
    print ("This image is DARK")
else:
    print ("This image is LIGHT")
```

Now I'm trying to expand this code in a way it **automatically takes all the images in a folder, converts them to thumbnails and analyses them one by one with this same formula**.

*EDIT* after various attempts with indentation, I wrote this:

```
import glob, os
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt
darklist=[]
lightlist=[]
dark=0
light=0
happylist=[]
sadlist=[]
size=128,128
for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    im=Image.open(infile)
    im.thumbnail(size)
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(file + ".thumbnail", "JPEG")
for infile in glob.glob("*.thumbnail"):
    im=Image.open(infile)
    colors=im.getdata()
    for item in colors:
        if sqrt((item[0]-255)**2 + (item[1]-255)**2 + (item[2]-255)**2) < sqrt((item[0]-0)**2 + (item[1]-0)**2 + (item[2]-0)**2):
            lightlist.append(item)
            light+=1
        else:
            darklist.append(item)
            dark+=1
    print ("Total light pixels=",light)
    print ("Total dark pixels=",dark)
    if len(darklist) > len(lightlist):
        print ("This image is DARK")
    else:
        print ("This image is LIGHT")
```

With this code I now have 7 different outputs (one for each image in my folder) but I noticed that the figures don't add up when counting the number of pixels of each image. Maybe there's something wrong with *darklist*, *lightlist* and their counters.

My general problem is: how to apply the Euclidean distance formula to each image in a folder? Now I have 7 but I could have much more..

Comment: Your problem is unclear: You're guessing it's working simultaneously on all values at the same time, or is that *what you want*? Do you just want a confirmation of your guess?

Comment: Have you considered using numpy?

Comment: When i call im.getdata() and ask len(im.getdata()) my output is:
`16384
16384
16384 (x7)`
that is 7 lists of 16384 items each (the number of pixels in each image)
I would like now to apply my formula to each list sequentially in a way that I have 7 outputs like:
`Total light pixels= *
Total dark pixels= *
This image is DARK(or LIGHT)`
Hope I've been more clear now :)

Comment: "so i need a way to analyse all of them without opening them one by one..." I don't understand that: you already have the thumbnails (after all, you just created them); why re-open them? Just use the data you already have.

Comment: I don't understand why `im.getdata()` gives you 7 lists: 3 or 4 makes sense, one for each colour/alpha channel. You're looping over each image individually (`for infile in glob.glob(...)`), thus opening each image individually, and thus `im.getdata()` returns the data for 1 image only.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I already have all the thumbnails opened..I just need to apply the formula on each one.
 I think I have 7 lists because I have 7 images in my folder, so when I ask `im.getdata()`, it grabs the data from each image. Then, each list itself has 16384 items,(each one is a tuple of 3 numbers from 0 to 255 because the image has 3 channels, RGB).
What i can't understand is how can I apply the formula over each image in my folder and have all the outputs..

Comment: Can you update your second code with that `len(img.getdata())` statement, that produces that list of 7 images? Because with your current code, I can't reproduce that: I just get the number of pixels for the corresponding image, not a list of images. So it appears you're doing something else than the code you're showing here.

Answer (score 0):

For the second loop, you can do something like this to operate on all pixels at once (but you still have to loop through each image separately):

```
import numpy as np
import glob
for infile in glob.glob("*.thumbnail"):
    im=Image.open(infile)
    data = np.array(im.getdata())
    result = np.sqrt((data[..., 0] - 255)**2 + (data[..., 1] - 255)**2 +
                     (data[..., 2] - 255)**2)
    <etc>
```

Comment: I edited my question with the actual code, so you can reproduce it. I don't have numpy right now, I'll install it and give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem: seems like *lightlist*, *darklist* and their counters must be written right before the `for item in colors` loop and not on top of all loops.